# charts are not being show with wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chart.js, wicked-pdf

I'm using chart.js in my rails project with activeadmin I have this in my action

```
controller do
  before_action :set_query, only: :index
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: "file_name", javascript_delay: 3000, layout: "application_pdf.html.erb"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and I have this in my view

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have following in my application_pdf.html.erb layout

```
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "active_admin.js" %>
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "Chart" %>
```

charts are properly being show in html but in pdf I am not able to see them what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer so that it can help others I just set responsive option as false and everything start working fine

```
options: {
  responsive: false
}
```

Comment: Could you add more information about where exactly this should go?

Comment: Do you know why this is the case?
Is there another way to fix this?
I have multiple charts, and I don't want to set this for all of them, also because we need the responsiveness when not viewing as PDF.

Comment: You can use options' value based on your action_name to enable it